# Add list stats to text paragraph

Tags: 2010, stats

SharePoint 2010:

I have a bit of a random question, and google has not been very helpful - probably because I don't know how to word the question into something googleble.

I have a sharepoint list which people in the company log in to and create new work tasks.  I have a link to this list which is fine, and obviously allows me to see what has been added and how many new items there are.

What I would like to do is on the site home page have a free text field and have something like "You have had 10 new items added" or "There are 9 tasks due in the next 7 days".  The numbers here being dynamic and driving off of the info I already have the sharepoint list.

Is such a thing possible in OOB sharepoint?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing is not possible OOB. You could write JavaScript code and use CAML query to filter the list according to your requirements. You can do this using REST api / SPServices in a Content Editor web part.

If CAML query is not an option for you, you can create a view with the filter and query the view for the item count.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I will investigate your suggestion. :)